# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, netbeans-6.9

Trying to run a RESTful webservice using Glassfish and NetBeans6.9.1
I keep getting this exception...It seems to be related to aopalliancce.jar? NB does not include it I downloaded and added it...no joy.

Does anybody have any idea how to get rid of this thing?

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Answer (score 6):

You are using Spring which requires the aopalliance library. Download it from here and include in your classpath: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0. You can also grab it using maven from the same place.

Answer (score 0):

while i'm a bit late to the party, i've noticed this was a helpful bit of information: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?38114-getting-noClassDef-found-error-eventhough-correct-jar-is-present